# How to get facebook first name and last name from checkbox plugin?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there a way to get profile info when Checkbox Plugin rendered?

I would like to pass PSID via "ref" param. Now I can get PSID only when a user sends some text to page.

Comment: no, there is no way to get any user data without user interaction. that would be weird, to get something (even if it is "only" an id) just because a user visits your website.

Comment: @luschn Thank you. That makes sense

Comment: i put it into an answer, because there´s actually nothing else to say about it anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to get any user data without user interaction. It would be weird to get user info (even if it is "only" an id) just because a user visits your website.